# How to write a macro similar to CGRectZero for a custom struct

Tags: ios, struct, macros, c-preprocessor

I have a custom struct and I'd like to have a define similar to CGRectZero.

This way I can have a void structure I can test against for not valid values.

Comment: CGRectZero isn't a void struct. It's a CGRect with 0 values.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't explain in detail. What I mean is that I need a struct with some value that I can identify as not valid.

Comment: Btw, `CGRectZero` is not a macro, but an extern variable (at least in the iOS 7 SDK).

Comment: Martin didn't know that. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its is mixer of c and objective c code. In which case you have to name the file with .mm extension.

```
#define MyStructZero MyStructMake(0,0)

MyStruct MyStructsMake(int,int);

typedef struct MyStruct {
    int a;
    int b;
} MyStruct;
```

c function

```
MyStruct MyStructMake(int a, int b)
{
    MyStruct s;
    s.a = a;
    s.b = b;
    return s;
}
```

testing in obj c

```
 - (void) testStruct
    {
        MyStruct m = MyStructZero;
        NSLog(@"%i", m.a);

    }
```

Comment: I noticed now that the MyStructMake is incorrect I think. It will always create a (0,0) struct ignoring the parameter passed, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Since `CGRectZero` is equivalent to `CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)` then you should use a similar approach. Write a function which initializes your structure and make a macro:

```
MyStructMake(int i, float f, char c, double d);
#define MyStructZero MyStructMake(0, 0.0, '0', 0.0)
```